# Azure Pipeline with Review Apps - Cleanup after merge

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I've been setting up a pipeline for our project with Azure Pipeline using yaml. Currently adding review apps with Azure Kubernetes Service and was wondering how we should clean up after the PR is merged.

We are building docker images, pushing them to our registry, deploying them to a new dev space. Then it's all just left there.

After merge we're never going to bed those images again, not like we're going to deploy from a unapproved PR and there's dozens of them every day. We also would like to delete the review app and take down those extra deployments after we're done with them

I can't find anything in the documentation for this. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is [az image delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/image?view=azure-cli-latest#az-image-delete) working for you?

Comment: I meant how to hook this into the pipeline so that it does it automatically when the PR is completed.

Comment: When the PR is completed and merged to master branch, master branch trigger a CI build to invoke [Azure CLI](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureCLIV2/Readme.md) task to delete the image. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yeah pretty much. We're only building and pushing the images because we are deploying review apps to AKS with DevSpaces. I've done similar before with Gitlab CI where they have an [on_stop](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#environmenton_stop) action where you can cleanup the review app environment so in this case I would like to delete the review app and namespace from k8s and then delete the image from ACR.

Comment: In DevOps, Azure CLI task should help you, have you checked it?

Comment: Does Azure CLI task solve your issue?

Comment: I'm sure I could write a task that does what I want. This isn't the problem. There's no trigger point for running it. You cannot schedule a pipeline to run on PR completion. A colleague has found we can configure a web hook to run on PR status change so we may have to look into implementing something with that. It seemed like wanting to clean up review apps after merging the PR that created it would be a built in feature but apparently not.

Comment: When the PR is completed, the change would merge to `master` branch. You can set up a CI build for `master` branch. Is this working for you?

Comment: If you have any update, kindly post back.

Comment: I've just been looking at this again now. A CI build for the master branch does not have the information about the PR that just completed. I want something that triggers on PR completion to go to kubernetes and delete the review app. I don't understand why this isn't a feature. We have a team of 40 submitting PRs all day. If the review apps are not cleaned up after them we will very quickly end up with 100s of namespaces and pods running in the cluster, just sitting there never to be used again. The best solution I've found so far seems to be a service hook that runs an azure function

Answer (score 0):

I’ve been wondering the same thing, how does one clean-up all the “ephemeral” resources? Seeing the documentation says “ephemeral” I had hoped this functionality was built in.

Even though we trigger on `master`, I don’t believe there is enough information available in the pipeline to know which PR caused the commit to `master`, thus we cannot be guaranteed to tear down the correct review app.

Comment: See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63057230/161865 I've found a way that seems to be working to achieve this but it is a bit convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this today and think I've got it working.
I made a new pipeline that uses the kubectl task to delete the review app namespace, it also uses the azure cli task to run az acr purge to delete the images created for the PR, the tags of which are prefixed with the pr number so it can identify them.
I set this pipeline to not run with CI and not download the source.
Then I made an Azure Function that uses calls the Run Pipeline API to run it, passing the PR number as a variable to the pipeline.
Finally I used Service Hooks to invoke the Azure Function on PR Updated.

The only thing outstanding is the Environment Resource that is created automatically on the DevOps site does not get deleted. I cannot find an API for this so we might have to live with that.

Answer (score 0):

By using browser dev tools and click the delete button in ADO I managed to find out how to delete environment resources using the Azure DevOps Rest API.

You can send:

```
DELETE <azure-dev-ops-base-url>/<organization>/_apis/distributedtask/environments/{environment-id}/providers/kubernetes/{resource-id}?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

To find environment-id and resource-id use:

```
GET: <azure-dev-ops-base-url>/<organization>/_apis/distributedtask/environments?api-version=6.0-preview.1
GET: <azure-dev-ops-base-url>/<organization>/_apis/distributedtask/environments/{environment-id}?expands=resourceReferences&api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer OPs question though.